# PageMethod and URL Rewrite

Tags: .net, url, url-rewriting

I'm putting a whole system with URL Rewrite and use the MapRoute. My problem is that Ajax calls are generated by PageMethods error because the URL Rewrite. It is as if the [WebMethod] was not found.
Does anyone know how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Add code in Application_BeginRequest (Global.asax) to check for the file extensions (.asmx /aspx) in Context.Request.Path. and Rewrite (Context.RewritePath) it to the one that is set in url mappings.